# Exiting vs Deactivating a Virtual Environment

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Is there really a difference between exiting, `exit`, and deactivating, `deactivate`, your virtualenv terminal shell when working with virtual environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much for most of virtual environments. With `exit` the current shell exits and you are in its parent shell. `deactivate` cleans up environment for the current shell. No big deal.

But there is a subtle case where the difference matters — temporary environments. Temporary environments is a feature of virtualenvwrapper. You create a temporary environment and virtualenvwrapper removes it on deactivating. Simply exiting in that case is not enough.